# Why is there a CORS block even though there is no CORS restriction on my backend?

Tags: java, reactjs, cors, cxf, tomcat9

I’m currently having problems with CORS in Tomcat, when I consume a service from React from another domain I receive the following error
`Access to fetch at 'https://tomcat:8443/post/service ' from origin 'https://domainReact:8443/react' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`
My configuration on the backend is as follows:
Tomcat9/conf/web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.request.decorate</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Allows-Origin,alias,Authorization,customerId</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>1728000</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CSRF</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
            <param-value>/html,/html/</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CSRF</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Network

```
General:
Request URL: https://tomcat:8443/post/service
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: 172.16.0.233:8443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request:
:authority: https://tomcat:8443
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /post/service
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
access-control-request-headers: alias,authorization,content-type,customerid
access-control-request-method: POST
access-control-request-private-network: true
origin: https://domainReact:8443/react
referer: https://domainReact:8443/react/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site

Response:
Control-Request-Headers
cache-control: private
content-length: 683
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

I have two custom headers, the API is exposed with JAX-RS and has no CORS filters.

I tried removing the tomcat/conf/web.xml filter, however, I received the same error. I tried consuming the service from Java and it worked without problems. The problem arises when it is consumed with React or Javascript. I added my custom headers to the Tomcat filter, but the result is the same when consumed from React.
I still don’t understand why the headers are not visible in the response when the service is consumed. Is there something that could be misconfigured in Tomcat?

Comment: Change the value of `cors.exposed.headers` to `alias,authorization,content-type,customerid`.

Comment: I have already added what you mentioned, however, I still cannot see the headers in the response and, even worse, I continue to have the CORS block. :(

Comment: Ah, hold on, I've just noticed something in the request: `access-control-request-private-network: true`. You're sending a request from a more public to a more local network; see https://github.com/WICG/local-network-access. Not sure Tomcat's CORS thing supports that yet.

Comment: A few days ago I solved it, the conclusion is as follows:
1. In my web.xml I had a security-constraint filter which was blocking OPTIONS requests.
2. Adding custom headers is also part of the solution because if they are not added, the request is blocked.
3. Adding or keeping in mind the Access-Control-Request-Headers header is also part of the solution because this header is allowed to enable the validation of custom headers and others. 
Thank you for your help @jub0bs, it was greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Remember that, on Stack Overflow, you can write an answer to your own question.